# Question regarding the min plus product of adjacency matrices.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

For an adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph with $n$ vertices. We know that the $k^{th}$ min plus power tells us the minimum weight path of length $k$. Then why do we only need to compute up until to the number of vertices the graph has to the minimum cost path of any length? That wouldn't tell us the minimum weight path of say length $n+1$. Could you clarify this please.

In the course that I am taking, there is no difference between a path and a walk.